# The first console app in C#

Tags: c#

I recently started to learn C#,so I tried to make something simple,but can not make the program to be 100% functional.I did it in Visual Studio and with every value given,the answer is the same

> Bigger than 0

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        int userinput = Console.Read();
        if (userinput > 0) Console.Write("Bigger than 0");
            else if (userinput < 0) Console.Write("Less than 0");
                    else Console.Write("Equal to 0");
        Console.Write("\nPress <ENTER> to exit\n");
        Console.ReadKey();

        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Console.Read()` method read the *code* of the key pressed, not an integer value typed in the console. You have to use `Console.ReadLine()` to read the full string and convert it into an integer, like this:

```
int userinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Note that in case the input string won't be a proper integer number, the program will fail. You can consider using [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and handling invalid input.

Comment: Correct, but your way to solve the problem will cause other problems if the user types something that cannot be converted to an integer. Please suggest to use Int32.TryParse

Comment: @Steve Yes, sure it will. However, it's fine for basic learning IMO. Anyway, will update my answer.